# capturing document level keypress events with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

i've been trying to capture document level key press events in a webpage but

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'a', keyevent_cb);
```

fails to respond consistently in firefox. works great in IE (which is kind of a trip). any recommendations? i've attempted other solutions without jquery and they also fail for firefox.

so i'm open to any result that works consistently (jquery or not). thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `keyevent_cb` do? Is there the suggestion of any errors therein?

Comment: it's just a call back function. prints an alert box.

Comment: Do you want to fire the callback on all keypress events or only under certain conditions?

Comment: all key presses and subsequent.

Answer (score 3):

The following attaches a keypress event listener to the body element:

```
$("body").on("keypress", function (e) {
    // logic for key event here
});
```

With your `keyevent_cb` callback, you could simply do:

```
$("body").on("keypress", keyevent_cb);
```

Comment: i'm getting an error message telling me "body" doesn't have an 'on' method.

Comment: The `.on()` method was added to version 1.7 of jQuery.  Consider upgrading if you would like to take this approach.  Documentation can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    switch(e.which)
    {
        // user presses the "a"
        case 97: doSomething(); break;
    }
});
```

Comment: i've tried variations of that and they work great on IE. as for firefox, it works 1 time then it doesn't work after that. this is a really annoying problem.

Comment: What are you doing in your callback, I just tested it on IE, chrome, and firefox latest and they all work.

Comment: i've loaded the page locally and haven't been using a debugger.