# How can I make scanned data automatically be entered into an input field upon scanning?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, focus, scanning

I am trying to develop a simple Android application for virtual warehousing. However, to make it easier on people using the app, I want the app to automatically input the data into a text field upon scanning, instead of clicking on the field first. So far, I have tried a few different jquery and javascript snippets of code, but nothing seems to work.

Also, I am using Appery.io to build this application.

Comment: What do you mean by "scanning"? Scanning could mean a number of things.

Comment: I mean "scanning" like a barcode scanner. The barcode scanner is built into the device and has a dedicated key on the side (it is a Motorolla TC55). Everything in my app works fine, except the app does not automatically focus on the textbox and I have to scan something twice before it inputs the scanned data into the box.

Answer (score 0):

From [Android: Listening for barcode scanner button being pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677725/android-listening-for-barcode-scanner-button-being-pressed)

You want to listen to the BUTTON_L1 keydown event and then set the focus to the text field.

And for jquery keypress try this one
[capturing document level keypress events with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510470/capturing-document-level-keypress-events-with-javascript)

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    alert(e.which)
});
```

This should tell you which button was pressed.